# How to write uint32 to csv file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, csv, uint32

I have an array of uint32 integers in MATLAB.
I want to export them to CSV file. When I use csvwrite() i get an exponent form..

```
b = uint32([1873569684     6411863   942650153  1666833080  3111076679])
csvwrite('tmpw.csv', b)
```

and the CSV result is:

```
1.8736e+09,6.4119e+06,9.4265e+08,1.6668e+09,3.1111e+09
```

instead of

```
1873569684,6411863,942650153,1666833080,3111076679
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csvwrite` writes a maximum of five significant digits. If you need greater precision, use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) with a precision argument.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick:
`dlmwrite('tmpw.csv', b, 'precision', 10)`